# Can i change things while debug mode is running in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, slick2d

so as the title states, can i change things while debug mode is running an application in Eclipse? You know like colors or stuff like that, I've seen Notch (Creator of Minecraft) do this thing when he was making "Escape" in 48 hours. I think that if I can do that then is more easy for me to change things like, moving buttons in the main menu, changing backgrounds or at least text colors.

PS: I'm using Slick2D
Thanks and have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do the following:

- Window->Open perspective->Debug
- Add a breakpoint somewhere in your code where applicable
- Window->Show view->Variables
- Run->Debug
- When the debugging pauses because of your breakpoint, go to the variables panel and change whatever value has been assigned so far (in the "Values" column).
- Run->Resume (or Step Over, or Step Into) to continue debugging
- The program will resume with your new value assigned to the variable